# Java regex with quantifier: replace matches by dynamically generated string

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I want to replace all matches in a String with a dynamic number of characters; let's use `[\d]+` as a simple example regex:

Desired results:

1. `1984` -> `DDDD`
2. `1` -> `D`
3. `123456789` -> `DDDDDDDDD`
4. `a 123 b ->`a DDD b`

The common Java approach for replacing regex matches looks like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\d]+");
String input = [...];
String replacement = ???;
String result = p.matcher(input).replaceAll(replacement);
```

My question is: do I have to extract the individual matches, measure their lengths, and then generate the replacement string based on that? Or does Java provide any more straightforward approach to that?

**Update**: I actually under-complicated the problem by giving rather simple examples. Here are some more that should be caught, taking more context into account:

1. `<1984/>` (Regex: `<[\d]+/>`) -> `DDDDDDD`
2. `123.` -> `DDDD`, whereas: `123` -> `123` (i.e. no match)

*Note*: I am **not** trying to [parse HTML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: You're over-complicating this. Just use `\d` with replacement as `D` as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/oXdZDK/1)

Comment: If you just want to replace numbers with `D` why does the match length matter at all? Just do `input.replaceAll("\\d", "D");`

Answer (score 1):

You're really overthinking/overcomplicating this. Just use `\d` with replacement as `D` [as seen here](https://regex101.com/r/oXdZDK/1/). There's no need to get the length of the string or do any additional processing; just a straight up `replaceAll()`

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/tp5bde)

```
final String[] a = {"1984","1","123456789","a 123 b"};
for (String s: a) {
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\d","D"));
}
```